# List items with alternating heights messing rows

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am having trouble with a list which has items with alternating heights based on the content. This causes the rows to break as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/PYRGb/ Try re-sizing the display view to see the effect.

What i would ideally like is for the list item to continue to the next row with space enough to make a row without hitting the edge of the above row. Is this possible?

- I know i have mentioned 'rows' and a table could be a solution but I
  am using lists to keep the display fluid and adaptable to a range of
  devices.
- Only solution i have found is to set a `min-height` that i am certain
  content will not overflow like so: http://jsfiddle.net/PYRGb/1/ But i
  really cannot predict the amount of content in the list items and
  would like the list item to adapt height if possible.

EDIT: Just a note, if you see the resize the display to have 3 columns, you can see the effect I need but it doesn't work in other situations. (Not sure if this is the same in all browsers, I am using Chrome 26)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the float and make the li display as inline-block with vertical align top.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevendwood/PYRGb/2/

```
ul li{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #eaeaea;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

You can set vertical align to middle or whatever you prefer.